# PL/SQL Developer connected to database but no results displayed

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

[Not get result when running command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y28Id.jpg)

Using SQL*Plus there is no problem and I get the results.

No error message when connecting to PL/SQL Developer.

Confirmed all the environment variables are set correctly.

telnet and port is open

And other reason for this issue ? thanks .

1.environment variables right

2.Tnsnames.ora file right

3.telnet the database server and port no problem

Comment: You tagged the question with a PL/SQL tag. That's a *language*, but I presume you have problems with a GUI tool named PL/SQL Developer. Is that so? If YES, consider fixing tags. BTW, did you actually run that SELECT statement? I don't use PL/SQL Developer so I don't know how to run it; I doubt that it is just a simple ENTER, might be e.g. CTRL+ENTER or "Run" icon in the toolbar or something like that.

Comment: I use PL/SQL Developer a lot and I have never seen this. Is it the same for every command? Is it just SQL windows - what happens in a Command window? Has this installation ever worked for you? From the screenshot it appears it ran in 3 seconds (so there doesn't seem to be a problem with your database connection, otherwise it would give a "Not connected" error message) but there is no results grid. This is probably one for the Allround Automations support forum https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=3&page=1